# Using a cursor throughout a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I am somewhat new to PL/SQL, and am having a little trouble using a cursor that I created. I am writing a procedure that sends emails to particular people.   Here is the relevant code:

```
sql stmt := ' -- All my sql is in here -- ';

open email_cursor for sql stmt;
fetch email_cursor into term, award, desc, id, name, xmdt;

.....


if v_id is not null then
    email_adr := schema1.get_email_adr(v_id);   --This is partly where problem is.

    if v_opt_ltr = 'Y' then       --a variable that decides if an email should be sent

                  UTL_MAIL.SEND (sender => email_from,
                       recipients => email_adr,
                       subject => v_email_subject,
                       mime_type => 'text/html',
                       message => email_body );

    END IF;

END IF;
```

Okay, so I dont get any errors or anything when I run this, but for some reason when I run the function for the email_adr variable it fails, and doesnt give me anything, and in turn wont send an email.

Another question (because I am new to cursors):  The v_id in the cursor should have about 25 records, if I run the line  "stu_email := schema1.get_email_adr(v_id);" will this give me all 25 records, and then will the "utl_mail.send" send an email to all the recipients?

Comment: Have you inpected the values of the parameters to UTL_MAIL.SEND? Have you tried sending a mail with UTL_MAIL using hardcoded parameters?

Comment: yes, I have, and it works fine.  If I hard code all of the email variables (including the recipient) it works fine.  It is just being able to use that variable (v_id), and get all 25 records with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you cursor is inside the `get_email_adr` function, is that right? Althought none of those variables looks obviously like an email address, so I'm a little confused.

If so then it all depends on how the code inside the `get_email_adr` function works. Every time you `open` a cursor it "resets" it. So if you want to combine all 25 records you'll need to have some code for it. Something like this:

```
FUNCTION get_email_adr( f_id IN NUMBER ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    result VARCHAR2(32000);
    CURSOR cur_email ( c_id IN NUMBER ) IS
        SELECT email_address FROM some_table WHERE id = c_id;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN cur_email( f_id )
    LOOP
        IF( result IS NULL )
        THEN
            result := rec.email_address;
        ELSE
            result := result || ',' || rec.email_address;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN result;
END get_email_adr;
```

Does that kind of answer you question or have I missed the point entirely?